# sqlconcat two variables postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

Im writing a psql function. I want to do a concat between two variables inside psql.
and im getting syntax_error.

Let's notice that date_contract is of type date.

Thank you Who can help me

```
declare
result_table regclass := $$public.contract$$||text;
time_now time
BEGIN
   execute $$SELECT MIN(date_contract) FROM $$||result_table INTO date_;
   execute  $$SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::time FROM $$||result_table INTO time_now;
 execute $$
INSERT INTO $$||result_table||$$
(id, dat_beg_contract, dat_end_contract,date_contract, long_c)

   SELECT id, dat_beg_contract, dat_end_contract, sum(extract(epoch from (least(s.dat_beg_contract, gs.date_contract||time_ + interval '1 day')::timestamp -
                           greatest(s.dat_beg_contract, gs.date_contract)
                          )
              ) / 60) as long_c 

   $$;
   END;
```

Comment: something like? `.., date_contract||time_now,..`

Comment: @JimJones  thank you but got this error psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "time_now" does not exist

Comment: it's because `time_now` does not exist in your table :) I will add an example as an aswer for you to take a look

Comment: btw: in your code there is no indication that the table `tab` exists! I will add two examples with anonymous code block and function

Answer (score 0):

This code block might give you an idea of how to concatenate variables

```
DO $$
DECLARE
rec1 text;rec2 text;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT ''foo'' ' INTO rec1;     
  EXECUTE 'SELECT ''bar'' 'INTO rec2; 
  RAISE NOTICE 'Option 1 %, Opiton 2: %', rec1||rec2, rec1||' '||rec2 ;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

NOTICE:  Option 1 foobar, Opiton 2: foo bar
```

**EDIT** Returning a query with a function

```
CREATE TABLE tab (id int);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (100),(42);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc (table_name TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (res int) AS $$
DECLARE v1 int; v2 int;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT max(id) FROM '||table_name INTO v1;     
  EXECUTE 'SELECT min(id) FROM '||table_name INTO v2;     
 RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || v1 || v2 ;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT myfunc('tab');
 myfunc 
--------
  10042
```

**EDIT 2** Example concatenating timestamp and integer

```
CREATE TABLE tab (id int);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (100),(42);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc (table_name TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (res text) AS $$
DECLARE v1 int; v2 timestamp;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT min(id) FROM '||table_name INTO v1;     
  EXECUTE 'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' INTO v2;     
 RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_literal(v1 || ' - ' ||v2) ;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT myfunc('tab');
  EXECUTE 'SELECT min(id) FROM '||table_name INTO v1;     
  EXECUTE 'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' INTO v2;     
 RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_literal(v1::text || ' - ' ||v2) ;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT myfunc('tab');

             myfunc             
--------------------------------
 42 - 2021-02-02 15:54:24.24179
(1 Zeile)
```

**EDIT 3** let me know if this works, so that I can clean the answer

```
CREATE TABLE tab (date_contract date);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (current_date+7),(current_date);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc (table_name TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (date_contract date, col_new text) AS $$
DECLARE date_ date;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT min(date_contract) FROM '||table_name INTO date_;     
 RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT date_contract,'|| quote_literal(date_|| ' ' ||current_time)  ||' FROM ' || table_name;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM myfunc('tab');

 date_contract |            col_new            
---------------+-------------------------------
 2021-02-09    | 2021-02-02 16:29:49.013344+01
 2021-02-02    | 2021-02-02 16:29:49.013344+01
(2 Zeilen)
```

Comment: thank you Jim, but i didn't got you ! :/ what is wrong in what i wrote please? (original pub)

Comment: @dsp perhaps this other example might be clearer

Comment: it's really weird i didn't succeed to resolve the error !! @Jim Jones

Comment: @dsp consider adding the following to your question: 1) create table statements to the tables involved, 2) insert statements with some sample data, 3) a brief description of your use case and 4) the exact expected result :) Doing so I believe we can find a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you !! Give me just 5 minutes. I will put more details. Danke again

Comment: @dsp I just added another try to my answer. I believe you're now close ;)

Comment: i updated my original post. Please have a look.

Comment: @dsp have you tried my last two edits? consider adding the following to your question: 1) create table statements to the tables involved, 2) insert statements with some sample data, 3) a brief description of your use case and 4) the exact expected result.